# PTIJ: Assur for a Kohen to die?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

If a Kohen is prohibited from becoming Tamei, and people become Tamei upon dying, then wouldn't it be prohibited for a Kohen to die?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A *kohen* is allowed to become *tame* to a close relative, and *adam karov etzel atzmo*, a person is his own relative, so it's all right. A *kohen gadol*, on the other hand, who cannot become *tame* even to a relative, cannot die unless he's a *mes mitzva*, someone who dies where there's no one around to bury him. (A *kohen gadol* can become *tame* to a *mes mitzva*.) That's why so many *kohanim g'dolim* died in the *kodesh kadashim* during the second Temple, so there'd be no one around when they died.

Comment: Same I guess for a Kohein amputee.

Comment: Eli wasn't smart dying right in front of the runner, then...bad timing...

Answer (score 2):

חס ושלום! We find throughout history many כהנים צדיקים who weren't נזהר in this. It has the status of מנהג ישראל, even though כהנים aren't technically ישראלים.

Do not speak further of this topic!

Comment: ?????מנהג ישראל

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed forbidden for a Kohein to die. In fact, it is explicitly codified in scripture:

> ויאמר יהוה אל משה דבר אל אהרן אחיך ואל יבא בכל עת אל הקדש מבית לפרכת
> אל פני הכפרת אשר על הארן **ולא ימות**

Comment: There's a typo in the last unbolded word. You switched the Alef and Hei

Comment: @double really?

Comment: @blue yes it's supposed to be אהרן לא ימות "don't die, aharon"

Comment: @double if you move the vawv also then maybe we got something

Comment: @blue there's no vav in aharon (well there's one place where until about 2 hundred years ago there was a machloket between different ashkenazi scribes if there should be a vav, but no one now does it and it was probably mistaken.)

Answer (score 0):

Keivan shemais naseh chafshi min hamitzvos. A dead person is patur from the mitzvos.

Answer (score 0):

The question is based on the premise that dead people are *tamei*. However, this premise is questionable.

The Gemara (Nidda 70b) discusses the *taharah* status of a once dead person after reincarnation:

> מתים לעתיד לבא צריכין הזאה שלישי ושביעי או אין צריכין

The simplest explanation of this *shaila* is whether dead people become impure or not. We know that someone who touches a corpse becomes impure. Is the corpse itself impure?

The Sifri (Parshas Chukas) *darshens* the following:

> כל הנוגע - נוגע במת טמא, אין מת עצמו טמא

It seems that only one who touches the body is rendered impure, not the body itself.

[However, see Rashi in Pesachim 18a that we consider everything to be touching itself; אין לך נגיעה גדולה מזו. This would contradict the above Sifri, which sounds like the corpse itself doesn't become impure. See also Chasam Sofer YD 337]